# How to add words with custom entities based on conditions in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to add some custom tags like "Product","Color" etc. to a sentence like **"This shoe is of blue color"** and the output format should be:
**[('This', 'DT'), ('shoe', 'NN'), ('is', 'BEZ'), ('of', 'IN'), ('blue', 'JJ'), ('color', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]**
Only the POS tags will be replaced by the custom tags.
So whatever word comes in the attribute list will get a tag and the ones that don't will get a tag of other;

```
attribute_list = ['shoe','footwear']
custom_tags_list = []
def custom_tags(sentence):
    for word in word_tokenize(sentence):
        for i,j in enumerate(attribute_list):
            if i == word:
               custom_tags_list.append(zip(word,"Product"))
            else:
               custom_tags_list.append(zip(word,"Other"))
     return custom_tags_list
```

Now, this function is giving the output as:

[custom tag output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii3jq.png)

Can someone please help me in understanding what I am doing wrong and how to get the desired output??
Desired output : **[('This', 'Other'), ('shoe', 'product'), ('is', 'Other'), ('of', 'Other'), ('blue', 'Color'), ('color', 'Other'), ('.', '.')]**

Comment: if i == word:  isnt i an index of attribute list,...you should compare with j

Comment: Yes.. Though the change in variable gives the same output:
custom_tags(sentence)
Out[63]: [[('I', 'O')], [('I', 'O')]] but thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you doing this on `python3`, Behavior of `zip` is very different in `python3`, Check this,

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.append(zip((1,2)))
>>> lst
[<zip object at 0x7f8d1deb8f08>]
>>> lst.append(list(zip((1,2))))
>>> lst
[<zip object at 0x7f8d1deb8f08>, [(1,), (2,)]]
```

Change your code like this, Actually you don't required `zip` here.

```
attribute_list = ['shoe','footwear']
def custom_tags(sentence):
    custom_tags_list = []
    for word,tag in word_tokenize(sentence):
        if word in attribute_list:
            custom_tags_list.append((word,"Product"))
        else:
            custom_tags_list.append((word,"Other"))
    return custom_tags_list
```

**Result**

```
In [135]: print custom_tags_list
[('This', 'Other'), ('shoe', 'Product'), ('is', 'Other'), ('of', 'Other'), ('blue', 'Other'), ('color', 'Other'), ('.', 'Other')]
```

Comment: Hi.. I tried out your suggestion but now what I am getting is :
custom_tags(sentence)
Out[57]: [[('I', 'O')], [('I', 'O')]]

Comment: @ShuvayanDas Updated my answer please check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rahul K P